# ConTeXt: maxwidth and scaling an image

Tags: graphics, context

When using `\externalfigure` with `height` and `maxwidth` at the same time `maxwidth` is not honored:

```
\externalfigure[#6][height=4cm, maxwidth=2cm, orientation=0]
```

gives an image of 4cm height and whatever width that yield.

Is it possible to ensure that an image is scaled proportionally so that it has a given height or a lower height when required to fit a maximum width?

Comment: with scale=100000 instead of width=10cm this works. thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to scale to the smaller of the desired height and width while keeping the aspect ratio, you have to choose the options as such:

```
\externalfigure[cow.pdf][height=4cm,width=2cm,factor=fit]
```

This is also documented in the Garden at https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/useexternalfigure

> If both `width` and `height` are set, the `factor` is important:
> `none`: image is deformed accordingly
> `max`: aspect ratio is kept, the image is scaled to the bigger (oversized) variant
> `fit`: aspect ratio is kept, the image is scaled to the smaller (fitted) variant